# Installing Varnish on port 8080 breaks local environment

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, magento2, varnish

I am having trouble installing Varnish on my local environment, I amusing ubuntu and apache 2, I need to install this for Magento 2 purposes, so I followed this tutorial, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-varnish-with-apache-on-ubuntu-12-04--3

Step two

The thing is that it mentiones to change from 80 to 8080, why cant I leave it with 80?

Because when I go to localhost/folder/folder2 this breaks , but if I add localhost:8080/folder/folder2 then it works

I understand that localhost:80 works by just typing localhost but its a really annoying to change my system for this. I will share the files that I have (withouth modifying for varnish):

sudo nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf

I am suppose to change "Listen 80" to "Listen 8080"

```
> # If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
> # have to change the VirtualHost statement in
> # /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
> 
> Listen 80
> 
> <IfModule ssl_module>     Listen 443 </IfModule>
> 
> <IfModule mod_gnutls.c>   Listen 443 </IfModule>
> 
> # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/lsapp/public"
    ServerName lsapp.dev
    <Directory /var/www/html/lsapp/public/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Answer (score 1):

Because that is how varnish works. It caches the content from its back end server so it must listen on port 80. It is the first layer. Your back end will listen on any other port. In your case it is apache which is listening on 8080.

In your case if you start apache in port 80 then you are directly accessing apache without caching anything in Varnish.

Comment: How do I know which port is my apache2 on? I assumed it is 80 because of the /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

<VirtualHost *:80>


In any case I would have to change my apache2 to listen liste to 8080 and when debugging site always add the localhost:8080/folder1/folder2 ?

Comment: You can use “netstat -ntlp” to check the listening tcp ports

Comment: If you bring Varnish in front on port 80 and apache in back end on port 8080 then you will be able to access the site using http://localhost/folder/folder2 assuming Varnish configuration is properly done

Comment: I used this tutorial -> https://websiteforstudents.com/install-apache2-with-varnish-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-server/ I still cannot access the site, it sais "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: Well I was getting "This site can't be reached" because in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf they said to change everything to <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>, mine by default was <VirtualHost *:80> so I changed it to <VirtualHost *:8080>  , so if I do localhost:8080/folder/folder2 the site will load but css is all messed up, if I access like localhost/folder/folder2 will get same error has before "This site can’t be reached"